# Git pull works in the terminal but not in bash file ( from webhooks )

Tags: bash, git, ssh, webhooks

When i run git pull origin master from the terminal on my ubuntu server it works perfectly.
I have 3 repositories and it works in each repository.

Now when i try to run the same command through the "push" from the webhooks i'm getting :

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The webhook seem to execute correctly :

[webhook][ff2a14] executing /home/ubuntu/projects/webhooks/admin-hooks/deploy.sh (/home/ubuntu/projects/webhooks/admin-hooks/deploy.sh) with arguments ["/home/ubuntu/projects/webhooks/admin-hooks/deploy.sh"] and environment [] using /home/ubuntu/projects/myproject/foofolder/foofolder2 as cwd

and calling the bash file from the right directory : `/home/ubuntu/projects/myproject/foofolder/foofolder2`

the bash file is simply :

```
#!/bin/bash

git pull origin master
```

if i change directory manually and call the bash file from the right directory : `/home/ubuntu/projects/myproject/foofolder/foofolder2`   and run `git pull origin master` it will work.

The rsa key seem to be used properly since i can pull manually ( no ssh-add used , it's an ssh config file with files that don't have a passphrase... )

Last thing to note is that altought all 3 repositories in my hooks are configured there's one which is working fine..

Edit :

**i've just figured out that :
If i run the webhooks handler starting with "sudo" the hooks works for repo 1 and not for repo 2 and 3.
BUT if i run the handler without sudo it doesn't work for repo 1 or 2 but will work for the 3rd one.**

Each of my repository has it's own rsa key set registered in the ssh config file and configured in each repository.

Answer (score 0):

It is better for your hook to be more explicit, and:

- display its user (id -a), to check who is executing the webhook.
- displey the content of ~/.ssh (`ls -alrth ~/.ssh`)
- cd to the right path of the local repository
- display the remote origin URL used (`git remote -v`), to check it is an SSH one (`git@github.com:...`)

If the script works with `sudo` for `repo1`, that means `/root/.ssh` has the right `id_rsa` private key.
But first: make sure those repositories actually use an *SSH* URL.